# How to add a jquery on click on a button that was created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have buttons that was created dynamically. How to add a jquery onclick on this button? I am still new to jQuery.

This is how I created my buttons in jQuery:

```
  var language_add_button = document.createElement("button");
  language_add_button.setAttribute("id", "btnRemoveLanguage_" + ctr);
  language_add_button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-padding");
  language_add_button.setAttribute("type", "button");
```

This function creates buttons with id + ctr making them unique.

I know about

```
  $("#btnRemoveLanguage_").click(function (e) {
    RemoveLanguage(true);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

But since there is a counter when created, the buttons becomes btnRemoveLanguage_1, btnRemoveLanguage_2, etc.

How do I make sure that it is clicking the right button?

Comment: To add events to a dynamic button you need to know the parent (parent should be static). Thn you can add an event

Answer (score 0):

for dynamic event handling you can use: event-listener on parent element. [Document on event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

but as for now i have used document.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnRemoveLanguage_",function (e) {
    RemoveLanguage(true);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: There is a counter on btnRemoveLanguage_ making it btnRemoveLanguage_1, btnRemoveLanguage_2

Comment: this is just an example for the event delegation for your question. you can use your logic to loop with the classNames or ID and attach the eventlisteners.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
var language_add_button = document.createElement("button");
language_add_button.setAttribute("id", "btnRemoveLanguage_" + ctr);
language_add_button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-padding");
language_add_button.setAttribute("type", "button");

/*******************************
 *   Append the following code *
 *******************************/      
$(language_add_button).click((e)=>{
    RemoveLanguage(true);
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: I modify my code to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You would do:

```
$(document).on("click", "#your_id" , function() {
            // do something $(this) is your button
        });
```

Comment: The `#your_id` on this example is static. Unless you are saying to create a lot of this per ID._ctr

Comment: Use template literals for substituting the "static" #your_id, e.g. \`#{your_var}\`...

Answer (score 0):

`.click()` will only bind to existing elements in the document aka Direct binding. In your case (the element gets created dynamically), you will have to use Delegated binding like `.on()`.

```js
var buttonID = "btnRemoveLanguage_" + ctr;
var language_add_button = document.createElement("button");
language_add_button.setAttribute("id", buttonID);
language_add_button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-padding");
language_add_button.setAttribute("type", "button");

$(document).on("click", buttonID, function(e) {
    RemoveLanguage(true);
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).delegate(buttonID, "click", function(e) {
    RemoveLanguage(true);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[source](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind.

```
language_add_button.appendTo('/where you need to add/').bind('click', '/your callback function here/');
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a value on my button and changed it to class instead. This solved my problem

```
  var language_add_button = document.createElement("button");
  language_add_button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-padding btnRemoveLanguage");
  language_add_button.setAttribute("type", "button");
  language_add_button.setAttribute("value", ctr);


  $("#btnRemoveLanguage_").click(function (e) {
    var ctr = $(this).val();
    RemoveLanguage(true, ctr);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

With this, I only have 1 remove function and will work on ALL buttons with ctr as its value.

Answer (score 0):

Isn`t it easier to connect the listener to class, not to ID? Or create a data value and connect to it. That will add a listener to any new element automatically.

```
const language_add_button = document.createElement("button");
language_add_button.setAttribute("id", "btnRemoveLanguage_" + ctr);
language_add_button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-padding arrayOfMyButtons");
language_add_button.setAttribute("type", "button");

$(".arrayOfMyButtons").click(function (e) {
   // any logic inside
});
```

Comment: This is now the same in my answer. but instead of arrayOfMyButtons, I added a value in my buttons instead.